# Modificar símbolo de tag <Li> no PDF gerado através do iText

Tags: java, html, itext

Meio confuso título, mas o problema é um tanto simples.

Estou gerando um PDF através do iText e estou utilizando HTML por ser mais simples.

Estou realizando o exemplo abaixo o único problema é que gostaria de modificar o símbolo da tag `<li>` para um quadrado conforme abaixo:

`<li type='square'>Teste</li>`

Meu código:

```
public static final String DEST = "\\pdfteste\\html_2.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        try{
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new TestiText7().createPdf(DEST);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        writer.setInitialLeading(12);
        // step 3
        document.open();

        // step 4
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("<html><head></head><body>");
        sb.append("<ol><li>Teste</li>");
        sb.append("<li>Teste</li>");
        sb.append("<ul><li>Teste</li><li>Teste</li></ul>");
        sb.append("<li>Teste</li>");
        sb.append("<ul><li>Teste</li><li>Teste</li><ul><li type=\"square\">Teste</li></ul></ul>");
        sb.append("</ol>");
        sb.append("</body><html>");

        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                new StringReader(sb.toString()));

        // step 5
        document.close();
    }

}
```

Esse é o resultado no arquivo. Alguém passou por algo ou simplesmente não da pra fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá para fazer algo semelhante a CSS? Não sei se dá, mas se der, acho que esse seria o caminho.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ainda vou conferir se via CSS da certo, mas queria ir pela maneira mais simples.